# Jsoup 404 on a working website (Bing api)

Tags: java, android, jsoup, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to send the following request via Jsoup but for some reason I get an error:

```
String url= "http://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?subscription-key=" + "api_key" + "&q=" + "emojimovie" +"&aspect=wide";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?subscription-key="key"&q=emojimovie&aspect=wide
```

**CAN ANYONE HELP, PLEASE?**

Comment: Add a s to http ?

Comment: Jsoup is html parser. It works if that url is loaded. But input url you are providing its not opening in browser so check with the url.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it a HTTP connection, Jsoup is not able to connect so use selenium driver to connect the URL and parse the page source using Jsoup

```
WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url); // your URL
Document pageDoc=Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource()); // Here you get the pagesource
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("Your url")
             .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
             .referrer("http://www.google.com")
             .get();
```